# Live video streaming issue: Blank screen on iOS 17 with AVMutableMovie/AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, video-streaming, avfoundation, avplayer

I'm encountering an issue with live video streaming on iOS 17 using AVMutableMovie. I'm utilizing a wss URL to stream videos by capturing data in chunks (e.g., 5 seconds) and playing it. Upon completion of the 5-second segment, I load another 5 seconds using self.player.replaceCurrentItem(with: nextPlayerItem).
Despite listening to events via self.player.currentItem?.observe, the functionality appears to be working well on iOS 16 but consistently displays a blank video on iOS 17.

```
/**
     Plays next fragment set.
     */
    private func playNext() {
        let nextSet = self.dataCollector.getNextItem(length: self.configuration.frameDelay)
        if nextSet.count == self.configuration.frameDelay  {
            var playerTime:Int = self.player.currentItem != nil ? Int(CMTimeGetSeconds(player.currentTime())) : 0
            var allData = Data()
            allData.appendAll(dataSet: dataCollector.getFileType())
            nextSet.forEach { (data) in
                playerTime += 1
                allData.append(data.getFragmentData())
                self.currentFragmentTimes.updateValue(data.getFragmentTime(), forKey: playerTime)
            }
            if(allData.count > 0) {
                self.player.replaceCurrentItem(with: AVPlayerItem(asset: AVMutableMovie(data:allData, options:  nil)))
                self.playerInitializedTime = nil
                self.player.play()
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried to Replace the AvMutablePlayer with AVPlayer it seems working but there is flickering after each replacement of data buffer.

Comment: does anyone is facing the issue?